# How to run update/remove operations without transaction in spring jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a non-web application that will run in background, during its run period I don't need any transactions. I must ensure that every jdbc operation should be automatically committed immediately, but spring jpa doesn't allow that happened.

How could I avoid TransactionRequiredException without transaction opened ??

Answer (score 0):

Open a transaction. If you don't need an extended transaction and just want to do a quick update and commit it, you still need a transaction; just put `@Transactional` on the one method (or grab an `EntityManager`) and finish everything right there.